# How to remove rows from dataframe if column values don't match with all the values on the list

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have two lists with set of dates for the last week, and the week before the last:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime
import numpy as np
import time

today = datetime.date.today()
datesLast = [today + datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in range(-7 - today.weekday(), -0 - today.weekday())]
datesPrevious = [today + datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in range(-14 - today.weekday(), -7 - today.weekday())]
LastWeek = [date_obj.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') for date_obj in datesLast]
PreviousWeek = [date_obj.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') for date_obj in datesPrevious]

data = pd.read_csv("path/to/my.csv", quotechar='"')
```

I need to check if all the values from `LastWeek` list exist in my.csv (date column). If all the values exist then remove all rows with dates different than in the list. If some values don't exist in my.csv file then check if all the values from `PreviousWeek` exist and then remove all the other rows that have values different than the values on this list.

**my.csv**

```
date          ID
31-08-2020    1
01-09-2020    1
02-09-2020    1
03-09-2020    1
04-09-2020    1
05-09-2020    1
06-09-2020    1
07-09-2020    1 
08-09-2020    1 
09-09-2020    1 
10-09-2020    1
```

Desired output for the above:

```
 date          ID
31-08-2020    1
01-09-2020    1
02-09-2020    1
03-09-2020    1
04-09-2020    1
05-09-2020    1
06-09-2020    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas.Series.isin`:

```
con1 = df["date"].isin(LastWeek)
if con1.all():
    print(df[con1])
else:
    con2 = df["date"].isin(PreviousWeek)
    print(df[con2])
```

Output:

```
         date  ID
0  31-08-2020   1
1  01-09-2020   1
2  02-09-2020   1
3  03-09-2020   1
4  04-09-2020   1
5  05-09-2020   1
6  06-09-2020   1
```